# localhost/phpmyadmin erro 500

Tags: linux, apache, phpmyadmin

Fiz a instalação do phpmyadmin, funcionou corretamente, configurei os bancos e testei meus sites localmente.
Mas quando fui ligar o pc novamente tudo funciona corretamente, mas quando vou acessar localhost/phpmyadmin, apresenta erro 500.

***Arquivo "/etc/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd" esta vazio.***

**Erro no navegador**

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@localhost to
>   inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you
>   performed just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.
>
> Apache/2.4.10 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

**O log do /var/log/apache2/error.log :**

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/lib/php5/20121212/msql.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20121212/msql.so:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown
>   on line 0 [Sun Jun 28 21:07:15.004913 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid
>   1501] AH00163: Apache/2.4.10 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.12-2ubuntu4.4 configured
>   -- resuming normal operations [Sun Jun 28 21:07:15.004943 2015] [core:notice] [pid 1501] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
>   [Tue Jun 30 00:35:39.246401 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1501]
>   AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down PHP Warning:  PHP Startup:
>   Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20121212/msql.so' -
>   /usr/lib/php5/20121212/msql.so: cannot open shared object file: No
>   such file or directory in Unknown on line 0 [Tue Jun 30
>   13:46:38.867678 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1406] AH00163:
>   Apache/2.4.10 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.12-2ubuntu4.4 configured -- resuming
>   normal operations [Tue Jun 30 13:46:38.867710 2015] [core:notice] [pid
>   1406] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2' [Tue Jun 30
>   15:00:13.966856 2015] [authn_file:error] [pid 5421] (2)No such file or
>   directory: [client 127.0.0.1:35446] AH01620: Could not open password
>   file: /etc/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd [Tue Jun 30 15:00:17.832856 2015]
>   [authn_file:error] [pid 5422] (2)No such file or directory: [client
>   127.0.0.1:35447] AH01620: Could not open password file: /etc/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd [Tue Jun 30 15:00:34.908541 2015]
>   [authn_file:error] [pid 1547] (2)No such file or directory: [client
>   127.0.0.1:35464] AH01620: Could not open password file: /etc/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd [Tue Jun 30 15:00:43.087793 2015]
>   [authn_file:error] [pid 5415] (2)No such file or directory: [client
>   127.0.0.1:35471] AH01620: Could not open password file: /etc/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd [Tue Jun 30 15:00:46.369437 2015]
>   [authn_file:error] [pid 1548] (2)No such file or directory: [client
>   127.0.0.1:35472] AH01620: Could not open password file: /etc/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd [Tue Jun 30 15:00:50.280744 2015]
>   [authn_file:error] [pid 5421] (2)No such file or directory: [client
>   127.0.0.1:35475] AH01620: Could not open password file: /etc/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd [Tue Jun 30 17:54:32.515644 2015]
>   [authn_file:error] [pid 5422] (2)No such file or directory: [client
>   127.0.0.1:39847] AH01620: Could not open password file: /etc/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd [Tue Jun 30 17:54:49.863831 2015]
>   [authn_file:error] [pid 5424] (2)No such file or directory: [client
>   127.0.0.1:39849] AH01620: Could not open password file: /etc/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd [Tue Jun 30 17:54:51.616703 2015]
>   [authn_file:error] [pid 1550] (2)No such file or directory: [client
>   127.0.0.1:39850] AH01620: Could not open password file: /etc/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd [Tue Jun 30 17:54:54.522238 2015]
>   [authn_file:error] [pid 1551] (2)No such file or directory: [client
>   127.0.0.1:39851] AH01620: Could not open password file: /etc/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd [Tue Jun 30 17:54:57.637137 2015]
>   [authn_file:error] [pid 5425] (2)No such file or directory: [client
>   127.0.0.1:39852] AH01620: Could not open password file: /etc/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd [Tue Jun 30 21:46:40.423765 2015]
>   [authn_file:error] [pid 1547] (2)No such file or directory: [client
>   127.0.0.1:40351] AH01620: Could not open password file: /etc/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd [Tue Jun 30 21:46:41.115102 2015]
>   [authn_file:error] [pid 1548] (2)No such file or directory: [client
>   127.0.0.1:40352] AH01620: Could not open password file: /etc/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd [Tue Jun 30 21:46:41.629927 2015]
>   [authn_file:error] [pid 1549] (2)No such file or directory: [client
>   127.0.0.1:40353] AH01620: Could not open password file: /etc/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd [Tue Jun 30 21:46:43.407242 2015]
>   [authn_file:error] [pid 5422] (2)No such file or directory: [client
>   127.0.0.1:40354] AH01620: Could not open password file: /etc/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd [Tue Jun 30 21:47:10.720893 2015]
>   [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1406] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
>   PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/lib/php5/20121212/msql.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20121212/msql.so:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown
>   on line 0 [Tue Jun 30 21:47:47.877213 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid
>   1489] AH00163: Apache/2.4.10 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.12-2ubuntu4.4 configured
>   -- resuming normal operations [Tue Jun 30 21:47:47.877246 2015] [core:notice] [pid 1489] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
>   [Tue Jun 30 21:51:39.281072 2015] [authn_file:error] [pid 1513] (2)No
>   such file or directory: [client 127.0.0.1:36838] AH01620: Could not
>   open password file: /etc/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd [Tue Jun 30
>   21:51:42.727326 2015] [authn_file:error] [pid 1514] (2)No such file or
>   directory: [client 127.0.0.1:36839] AH01620: Could not open password
>   file: /etc/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd [Tue Jun 30 21:51:44.907725 2015]
>   [authn_file:error] [pid 3339] (2)No such file or directory: [client
>   127.0.0.1:36847] AH01620: Could not open password file: /etc/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd [Tue Jun 30 21:55:06.340377 2015]
>   [authn_file:error] [pid 1510] (2)No such file or directory: [client
>   127.0.0.1:36903] AH01620: Could not open password file: /etc/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd, referer:
>   https://askubuntu.com/questions/19127/how-to-access-phpmyadmin-after-installation
>   [Tue Jun 30 22:01:47.726980 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1489]
>   AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down PHP Warning:  PHP Startup:
>   Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20121212/msql.so' -
>   /usr/lib/php5/20121212/msql.so: cannot open shared object file: No
>   such file or directory in Unknown on line 0 [Tue Jun 30
>   22:01:48.756201 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3915] AH00163:
>   Apache/2.4.10 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.12-2ubuntu4.4 configured -- resuming
>   normal operations [Tue Jun 30 22:01:48.756240 2015] [core:notice] [pid
>   3915] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2' [Tue Jun 30
>   22:02:07.218562 2015] [authn_file:error] [pid 3919] (2)No such file or
>   directory: [client 127.0.0.1:36997] AH01620: Could not open password
>   file: /etc/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd [Tue Jun 30 22:02:08.733756 2015]
>   [authn_file:error] [pid 3920] (2)No such file or directory: [client
>   127.0.0.1:36999] AH01620: Could not open password file: /etc/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd [Tue Jun 30 22:02:17.126043 2015]
>   [authn_file:error] [pid 3921] (2)No such file or directory: [client
>   127.0.0.1:37000] AH01620: Could not open password file: /etc/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd [Tue Jun 30 22:04:17.857270 2015]
>   [authn_file:error] [pid 3922] (2)No such file or directory: [client
>   127.0.0.1:37020] AH01620: Could not open password file: /etc/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd [Tue Jun 30 22:04:18.417800 2015]
>   [authn_file:error] [pid 3923] (2)No such file or directory: [client
>   127.0.0.1:37021] AH01620: Could not open password file: /etc/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd [Tue Jun 30 22:04:18.638678 2015]
>   [authn_file:error] [pid 3919] (2)No such file or directory: [client
>   127.0.0.1:37022] AH01620: Could not open password file: /etc/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd [Tue Jun 30 22:04:18.840986 2015]
>   [authn_file:error] [pid 3920] (2)No such file or directory: [client
>   127.0.0.1:37023] AH01620: Could not open password file: /etc/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd [Tue Jun 30 22:04:19.437516 2015]
>   [authn_file:error] [pid 3921] (2)No such file or directory: [client
>   127.0.0.1:37024] AH01620: Could not open password file: /etc/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd [Tue Jun 30 22:04:23.563813 2015]
>   [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3915] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
>   PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/lib/php5/20121212/msql.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20121212/msql.so:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown
>   on line 0 [Tue Jun 30 22:04:24.680801 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid
>   4121] AH00163: Apache/2.4.10 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.12-2ubuntu4.4 configured
>   -- resuming normal operations [Tue Jun 30 22:04:24.680863 2015] [core:notice] [pid 4121] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
>   [Tue Jun 30 22:04:28.451575 2015] [authn_file:error] [pid 4125] (2)No
>   such file or directory: [client 127.0.0.1:37025] AH01620: Could not
>   open password file: /etc/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd [Tue Jun 30
>   22:04:29.169342 2015] [authn_file:error] [pid 4126] (2)No such file or
>   directory: [client 127.0.0.1:37026] AH01620: Could not open password
>   file: /etc/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd [Tue Jun 30 22:04:29.403142 2015]
>   [authn_file:error] [pid 4127] (2)No such file or directory: [client
>   127.0.0.1:37027] AH01620: Could not open password file: /etc/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd [Tue Jun 30 22:04:30.105557 2015]
>   [authn_file:error] [pid 4128] (2)No such file or directory: [client
>   127.0.0.1:37028] AH01620: Could not open password file: /etc/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd [Tue Jun 30 22:06:20.142989 2015]
>   [authn_file:error] [pid 4129] (2)No such file or directory: [client
>   127.0.0.1:37068] AH01620: Could not open password file: /etc/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd [Tue Jun 30 22:10:25.920766 2015]
>   [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 4121] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
>   PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/lib/php5/20121212/msql.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20121212/msql.so:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown
>   on line 0 [Tue Jun 30 22:10:27.044367 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid
>   4254] AH00163: Apache/2.4.10 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.12-2ubuntu4.4 configured
>   -- resuming normal operations [Tue Jun 30 22:10:27.044450 2015] [core:notice] [pid 4254] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
>   [Tue Jun 30 22:10:32.278887 2015] [authn_file:error] [pid 4258] (2)No
>   such file or directory: [client 127.0.0.1:37075] AH01620: Could not
>   open password file: /usr/share/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd [Tue Jun 30
>   22:10:32.888916 2015] [authn_file:error] [pid 4259] (2)No such file or
>   directory: [client 127.0.0.1:37076] AH01620: Could not open password
>   file: /usr/share/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd [Tue Jun 30 22:10:33.118904
>   2015] [authn_file:error] [pid 4260] (2)No such file or directory:
>   [client 127.0.0.1:37077] AH01620: Could not open password file:
>   /usr/share/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd [Tue Jun 30 22:10:33.292940 2015]
>   [authn_file:error] [pid 4261] (2)No such file or directory: [client
>   127.0.0.1:37078] AH01620: Could not open password file: /usr/share/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd [Tue Jun 30 22:10:33.491418 2015]
>   [authn_file:error] [pid 4262] (2)No such file or directory: [client
>   127.0.0.1:37079] AH01620: Could not open password file: /usr/share/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd [Tue Jun 30 22:10:34.102843 2015]
>   [authn_file:error] [pid 4258] (2)No such file or directory: [client
>   127.0.0.1:37080] AH01620: Could not open password file: /usr/share/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd [Tue Jun 30 22:10:34.296133 2015]
>   [authn_file:error] [pid 4259] (2)No such file or directory: [client
>   127.0.0.1:37081] AH01620: Could not open password file: /usr/share/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd [Tue Jun 30 22:10:34.476782 2015]
>   [authn_file:error] [pid 4260] (2)No such file or directory: [client
>   127.0.0.1:37082] AH01620: Could not open password file: /usr/share/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd [Tue Jun 30 22:14:42.034367 2015]
>   [authn_file:error] [pid 4381] (2)No such file or directory: [client
>   127.0.0.1:37268] AH01620: Could not open password file: /usr/share/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd [Tue Jun 30 22:15:21.700548 2015]
>   [authn_file:error] [pid 4260] (2)No such file or directory: [client
>   127.0.0.1:37376] AH01620: Could not open password file: /usr/share/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd, referer:
>   http://fabioled.blog.com/2011/06/07/acesso-negado-para-usuario-root-no-mysql-e-phpmyadmin-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-yes/
>   [Tue Jun 30 22:19:27.795437 2015] [authn_file:error] [pid 4262] (2)No
>   such file or directory: [client 127.0.0.1:37388] AH01620: Could not
>   open password file: /usr/share/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd, referer:
>   http://www.vivaolinux.com.br/dica/Acesso-negado-para-usuario-root-no-MySQL-e-PhpMyAdmin
>   [Tue Jun 30 22:20:14.349853 2015] [authn_file:error] [pid 4261] (2)No
>   such file or directory: [client 127.0.0.1:37402] AH01620: Could not
>   open password file: /usr/share/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd [Tue Jun 30
>   22:20:25.955177 2015] [authn_file:error] [pid 4260] (2)No such file or
>   directory: [client 127.0.0.1:37404] AH01620: Could not open password
>   file: /usr/share/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd [Tue Jun 30 22:20:36.769030
>   2015] [authn_file:error] [pid 4375] (2)No such file or directory:
>   [client 127.0.0.1:37405] AH01620: Could not open password file:
>   /usr/share/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd [Tue Jun 30 22:24:19.984276 2015]
>   [authn_file:error] [pid 4380] (2)No such file or directory: [client
>   127.0.0.1:37486] AH01620: Could not open password file: /usr/share/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd [Tue Jun 30 22:35:54.570197 2015]
>   [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 4254] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
>   PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/lib/php5/20121212/msql.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20121212/msql.so:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown
>   on line 0 [Tue Jun 30 22:35:55.614279 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid
>   5246] AH00163: Apache/2.4.10 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.12-2ubuntu4.4 configured
>   -- resuming normal operations [Tue Jun 30 22:35:55.614330 2015] [core:notice] [pid 5246] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
>   [Tue Jun 30 22:36:11.607772 2015] [authn_file:error] [pid 5251] (2)No
>   such file or directory: [client 127.0.0.1:37778] AH01620: Could not
>   open password file: /usr/share/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd [Tue Jun 30
>   22:36:21.047788 2015] [authn_file:error] [pid 5252] (2)No such file or
>   directory: [client 127.0.0.1:37798] AH01620: Could not open password
>   file: /usr/share/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd [Tue Jun 30 22:36:30.764584
>   2015] [authn_file:error] [pid 5254] (2)No such file or directory:
>   [client 127.0.0.1:37800] AH01620: Could not open password file:
>   /etc/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd [Tue Jun 30 22:37:11.376086 2015]
>   [authn_file:error] [pid 5250] (2)No such file or directory: [client
>   127.0.0.1:37801] AH01620: Could not open password file: /etc/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd [Tue Jun 30 22:37:13.360201 2015]
>   [authn_file:error] [pid 5253] (2)No such file or directory: [client
>   127.0.0.1:37804] AH01620: Could not open password file: /etc/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd [Tue Jun 30 22:37:15.145930 2015]
>   [authn_file:error] [pid 5250] (2)No such file or directory: [client
>   127.0.0.1:37801] AH01620: Could not open password file: /etc/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd [Tue Jun 30 22:37:19.461628 2015]
>   [authn_file:error] [pid 5253] (2)No such file or directory: [client
>   127.0.0.1:37804] AH01620: Could not open password file: /usr/share/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd

Comment: A extensão `msql.so` parece não existir, remova ela do php.ini e reinicie o servidor

Comment: Removi e continuou o erro @rray

Comment: Já tentou deletar esse `.htpasswd`?

Comment: Conseguiu resolver seu problema?